# What is the correct way to know which class an S4 object is?

Tags: r, r-s4

if I have an S4 object, I can inquire if it's an S4 object with isS4()

```
> cls <- setClass("Foo", slots = c("hello"))
> f <- new("Foo")
> isS4(f)
TRUE
```

But it's not clear to me how I can find "Foo". `class(f)` seems to work, but it seems to me it's exploiting S3 mostly. Is there a correct way to find which class an S4 object belongs to?

Yes, I know about `is()`, but that assumes you already know the class name (e.g. is(f, "Foo"). I want to get "Foo" as a result.

Comment: Try `attr(f, "class")[1]#
[1] "Foo"`

Comment: @akrun yes but it smells of a bit of a hack... S4 has a lot of functions, and there seem to be a lot of splitting between S3 classes and formal classes. I feel like there must be a function or a trick that targets S4 classes specifically, instead of accessing the attribute.

Comment: You may use `class(f)[1]` or `class(getClass(f))[1]` or `f@class[1]#
[1] "Foo"`

Comment: as far as I know, `class(f)` is correct for both S3 and S4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class(f)` is acceptable for both S3 and S4 objects. From the help page for `class` under "formal (S4) methods":

> "For objects which have a formal class, its name is returned by ‘class’ as a character vector of length one".